# How to Select Individual Rows by First Day of Month

Tags: r, date, select

I have a data frame as such

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Entity  Code  Day        stringency_index
  <chr>   <chr> <date>                <dbl>
1 Germany DEU   2020-01-21             0   
2 Germany DEU   2020-01-22             0   
3 Germany DEU   2020-01-23             0   
4 Germany DEU   2020-01-24             5.56
5 Germany DEU   2020-01-25             5.56
6 Germany DEU   2020-01-26             5.56
```

I want to select only rows that are the first of the month ie. 2020-02-01.
How can I do this?

Comment: try `dplyr::filter(df, lubridate::day(Day) == 1 )`

Answer (score 3):

In base R, you can extract the day of a date object using the format function, and filter using bracket notation. It's always best to provide sample data using dput() when asking questions on SO, but here is a simple example.

```
df <- data.frame(d = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-03-01"), by = 1))

df[format(df$d, format="%d") == "01",]

[1] "2020-01-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-03-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a combination of `as.yearmon` from `zoo` package and `lubridate`:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Day = ymd(Day)) %>% 
  group_by(yearMon = as.yearmon(Day)) %>% 
  arrange(Day) %>% 
  summarise(FirstDay = first(Day))
```

```
  yearMon   FirstDay  
  <yearmon> <date>    
1 Jan 2020  2020-01-01
2 Feb 2020  2020-02-01
```

data:

```
structure(list(Entity = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany"), Code = c("DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", 
"DEU"), Day = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-22", "2020-02-23", "2020-02-24", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-01-26"), stringency_index = c(0, 0, 0, 5.56, 
5.56, 5.56)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code using the `lubridate` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(Entity = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany"),
                 Code = c("DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU", "DEU"), 
                 Day = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-6"), by = 1),
                 stringency_index = c(0, 0, 0, 5.56, 5.56, 5.56))
```

Data:

```
   Entity Code        Day stringency_index
1 Germany  DEU 2020-01-01             0.00
2 Germany  DEU 2020-01-02             0.00
3 Germany  DEU 2020-01-03             0.00
4 Germany  DEU 2020-01-04             5.56
5 Germany  DEU 2020-01-05             5.56
6 Germany  DEU 2020-01-06             5.56
```

Use this code to select first day of a month:

```
df %>%
  filter(day(Day) == 1)
```

Output:

```
   Entity Code        Day stringency_index
1 Germany  DEU 2020-01-01                0
```